# How do I retrieve a list of active items from an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to get a list of employees who only have active hobbies and whose role is of type 'A'.

I tried using the below query but without any success.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
// Get all the employees with active hobbies and have a role of 'A'
var employees = people.find(item => item.key === 'Employees').employees.map(emp => emp.hobbies).filter(hobby => hobby.filter(h => h.active === true && h.roles.includes('A')));

console.log(employees);
```

```html
<script>
  var people = [{
    key: 'Employees',
    employees: [{
        name: 'joe',
        age: 20,
        hobbies: [{
          'active': true,
          name: 'skating',
          roles: ['C', 'A']
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'amy',
        age: 32,
        hobbies: [{
          'active': true,
          name: 'surfing',
          roles: ['A']
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'kate',
        age: 34,
        hobbies: [{
          'active': true,
          name: 'running',
          roles: ['C']
        }, {
          name: 'Chess',
          active: false,
          roles: ['C', 'A']
        }]
      }
    ]
  }];
</script>
```

**Update**

When I added more employees with new hobbies to the array, the accepted answer fails to produce the correct output. Why does this happen?

```
var people = [{
        key: 'Employees',
        employees: [{
                name: 'Steve',
                age: 50,
                hobbies: [{
                        active: true,
                        name: 'skating',
                        roles: ['C', 'A']
                    },
                    {
                        active: false,
                        name: 'skating',
                        roles: ['C', 'A']
                    },
                    {
                        active: true,
                        name: 'snooker',
                        roles: ['C', 'A']
                    },
                    {
                        active: true,
                        name: 'darts',
                        roles: ['C', 'A']
                    }
                ]
            },{
                name: 'joe',
                age: 20,
                hobbies: [{
                        active: true,
                        name: 'skating',
                        roles: ['C', 'A']
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'amy',
                age: 32,
                hobbies: [{
                        'active': true,
                        name: 'surfing',
                        roles: ['A']
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'kate',
                age: 34,
                hobbies: [{
                        active: true,
                        name: 'running',
                        roles: ['C']
                    }, {
                        name: 'Chess',
                        active: false,
                        roles: ['C', 'A']
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

var employees = people.find(item => item.key === 'Employees').employees.filter(employee => employee.hobbies.every(h => h.active && h.roles.includes('A')));
```

Comment: Just to clarify: "who only have active hobbies" means that all their hobbies have to be active? or just at least one? And "whose role is of type A" means they got at leadt one role? or their active hobby has to have that role? or all their hobbies have to have that role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things go wrong where you map the employees to their hobbies: this will make your final result consist of hobbies, not employees.

You need to stick to the employee level:

```js
var people = [{key: 'Employees',employees: [{ name: 'joe', age: 20, hobbies: [{'active': true, name: 'skating', roles: ['C', 'A'] }] },{ name: 'amy', age: 32, hobbies: [{'active': true, name: 'surfing', roles: ['A'] }] }, { name: 'kate', age: 34, hobbies: [{'active': true, name: 'running', roles: ['C']}, {name: 'Chess', active: false, roles: ['C','A']}] }]}];

var employees = people.find(item => item.key === 'Employees').employees
    .filter(employee => employee.hobbies.every(h => h.active && h.roles.includes('A')));
        
console.log(employees);
```

In an expression there is no need to compare a boolean property with `true`. Just use the property (`active` in this case).

Use `.some` instead of `.every` if the requirement is that employees have *at least* one such hobby, instead of requiring that *all* their hobbies comply with the condition.

Comment: You've given a very detailed answer and have answered my question. Thanks

Comment: I just updated my question again, it seems that the code you submitted does not produce the desired result when I add more items to the array. Please see above edit. Thanks

Comment: For that data 3 employees are returned. Kate is not among them because not *every* hobby she has is marked active. I can only repeat the last paragraph of my answer, since your question left ambiguous which of the two logics you were looking for. See also the comment made to your question by Jonas which you did not answer. I believe my answer is correct. You just have to choose `.every` or `.some` depending on your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
 .map(emp => emp.hobbies).filter(hobby =>
```

you map every employee to its hobbies, which fill result in a `2D` array:

```
 [[ { active: true }, { active: false } ], [/*...*/]]
```

Therefore `hobby` is not *one hobby* but an array of hobbies.

You said

> I'm trying to get a list of employees

... which means you actually don't want to `.map` to the hobbies, but rather `.filter` the employees and check if `ever` hobby fullfills certain rules:

```
 const employees = people.find(({ key }) => key === "Employees").employees;

 const isActive = hobby => hobby.active && hobby.roles.includes("A");

 const result = employees.filter(emp => emp.hobbies.every(isActive));
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want but the query isn't working as expected. I only want to display a list of employees with Active hobbies and who has a role of 'A'.
I tried running this query but it does not work : 

```var result = people.find(item => item.key === 'Employees').employees.filter(emp => emp.hobbies.every(h => h.active && h.roles.includes('A')))```

Answer (score 1):

`.map(emp => emp.hobbies)` returns an array of the hobbies, so the value of `employees` will be the filtered list of hobbies, not the employees that have those hobbies. You need to filter the employees, not map them.

```js
// Get all the employees with active hobbies and have a role of 'A'
var employees = people.find(item => item.key === 'Employees').employees.filter(emp =>
  emp.hobbies.every(h => h.active && h.roles.includes('A')));

console.log(employees);
```

```html
<script>
  var people = [{
    key: 'Employees',
    employees: [{
        name: 'joe',
        age: 20,
        hobbies: [{
          'active': true,
          name: 'skating',
          roles: ['C', 'A']
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'amy',
        age: 32,
        hobbies: [{
          'active': true,
          name: 'surfing',
          roles: ['A']
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'kate',
        age: 34,
        hobbies: [{
          'active': true,
          name: 'running',
          roles: ['C']
        }, {
          name: 'Chess',
          active: false,
          roles: ['C', 'A']
        }]
      }
    ]
  }];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do one call to `Array.prototype.filter` which checks the conditions you mentioned:

```
person.hobbies.every(y => y.active) && person.hobbies.every(z => z.roles.includes('A'))
```

```js
var people = [{
  key: 'Employees',
  employees: [{
      name: 'joe',
      age: 20,
      hobbies: [{
        'active': true,
        name: 'skating',
        roles: ['C', 'A']
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'amy',
      age: 32,
      hobbies: [{
        'active': true,
        name: 'surfing',
        roles: ['A']
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'kate',
      age: 34,
      hobbies: [{
        'active': true,
        name: 'running',
        roles: ['C']
      }, {
        name: 'Chess',
        active: false,
        roles: ['C', 'A']
      }]
    }
  ]
}];

let employees = people[0].employees.filter(x => 
  x.hobbies.every(y => y.active) && x.hobbies.every(z => z.roles.includes('A'))
)

console.log(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` & `filter`:

```js
var people = [{ key: 'Employees', employees: [{ name: 'joe', age: 20, hobbies: [{ 'active': true, name: 'skating', roles: ['C', 'A'] }] }, { name: 'amy', age: 32, hobbies: [{ 'active': true, name: 'surfing', roles: ['A'] }] }, { name: 'kate', age: 34, hobbies: [{ 'active': true, name: 'running', roles: ['C'] }, { name: 'Chess', active: false, roles: ['C', 'A'] }] } ] }];

const result = people.filter(x => x.key == 'Employees')
  .map(({employees}) => 
  employees.filter(x => x.hobbies.some(y => y.active && y.roles.includes('A'))))

console.log(result)
```

you could also use `reduce` & `filter`:

```js
var people = [{ key: 'Employees', employees: [{ name: 'joe', age: 20, hobbies: [{ 'active': true, name: 'skating', roles: ['C', 'A'] }] }, { name: 'amy', age: 32, hobbies: [{ 'active': true, name: 'surfing', roles: ['A'] }] }, { name: 'kate', age: 34, hobbies: [{ 'active': true, name: 'running', roles: ['C'] }, { name: 'Chess', active: false, roles: ['C', 'A'] }] } ] }];

const result = people.filter(x => x.key == 'Employees').reduce((r,{employees}) => 
{
  r.push(employees.filter(x => 
  x.hobbies.some(y => y.active && y.roles.includes('A'))))
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```